# Nested {{each}} loops in SendGrid Template

Tags: html, handlebars.js

Im trying to iterate an Array of Objects for putting their values in a Handlebars template using the each loop inside the structure of the array. Here you can see the array:

```
{
  "payload": {
      "order":{
          
    "id":"2255",
    "subtotal_gross_amount":"$100",
    "shipping_price_net_amount":"$20",
    "tax_amount":"$40",
    "subtotal_net_amount":"$160",
          
          "lines":[
              "product":{
                   "product_name" : "Air Football Pro",
                   
                   "varient":[
    {
    "varient_name":"X",
    "quantity":"2",
    "total_gross_amount": "$345",
    "total_tax_amount": "$345",
    "total_net_amount": "$345"
  },
      {
      "varient_name":"Y",
    "quantity":"1",
    "total_gross_amount": "$345",
    "total_tax_amount": "$345",
    "total_net_amount": "$345"
  }
              ]
              }
  ]
  }
}
}
```

And the each loop if've tried as you can see:

```
{{#each payload.order.lines}}
               <table class="module" role="module" data-type="code" border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;" data-muid="a16c3fb2-992a-4f39-8c80-c285b41a1eb1">
                  <tbody>
                      <tr>
                       <td>
                        <div style="font-family: inherit; font-size:25px; text-align: inherit;"><strong>{{this.product.product_name}}</strong> </div>
                        <div style="font-family: inherit; font-size:15px; text-align: inherit"> </div>
                        {{#each variant}}
                        <!--{{#if this.product.variant}}-->
                        <div style="font-family: inherit; font-size:25px; text-align: inherit;"><strong>{{varient.varient_name}}</strong></div> 
                        <div style="font-family: inherit; font-size:25px; text-align: inherit;"> </div> 
                        <div style="font-family: inherit; font-size:15px; text-align: inherit; padding: 2px;">Quantity: {{variant.quantity}} </div>
                        <div style="font-family: inherit; font-size:15px; text-align: inherit; padding: 2px;">Total_Gross_Amount: {{variant.total_gross_amount}} </div>
                        <div style="font-family: inherit; font-size:15px; text-align: inherit; padding: 2px;">Total_Tax_Amount: {{variant.total_tax_amount}} </div>
                        <div style="font-family: inherit; font-size:15px; text-align: inherit; padding: 2px;">Total_Net_Amount: {{variant.total_net_amount}} </div>
                        <!--{{/if}}-->
                        {{/each}}
                       </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
 {{/each}}
```

I don't know how to solve it or what I'm doing wrong. I appreciate any comment about this issue Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Just like you referenced `this.product.product_name`, you would need to reference

```
{{#each this.product.variant}}
```

This will begin an inner loop of iteration. In here you would reference attributes like `{{this.varient_name}}`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Steven White did not work for me.

The way it works is that the `this` variable is **replaced by the nested object reference**.

So just refer to it in nested loop as if it is in single loop.

```
{{#each payload.order.lines}}
           <table class="module" role="module" data-type="code" border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;" data-muid="a16c3fb2-992a-4f39-8c80-c285b41a1eb1">
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                   <td>
                    ...
                    {{#each this.product.variant}}
                    <div style="font-family: inherit; font-size:25px; text-align: inherit;"><strong>{{this.name}}</strong></div> 
                    ...
                    {{/each}}
                   </td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
           </table>
{{/each}}
```